# Low cost, liquid acid fertilizer

Tags: fertilizer, organic, strawberries

I am growing strawberries which I read prefer acid soil to alkaline one. I also read that using water that were used for beans soaking is recommended as a fertilizer. Will using it make my soil more acid? Or more alkaline?

Comment: If you haven't already done this, get a soil test before making any soil amendments. A couple sources I checked show strawberries like pH from 5.5 to 6.5, 6.5 isn't very "acid", so you may not need to do anything to your soil. I once knew a guy who put lime onto his vegetable garden every year "because that's what Grandpa did and he had a beautiful garden!" This guy's garden wasn't doing well, and when he got a soil test it showed that the garden had a pH of 7.8 - he was making his soil WORSE every year, not better, with his soil amendment.

Comment: Strawberries grow near me on alkaline clay based soils and do quite well.  As Jurp says get a soil test as you are likely to find no action is required.